# Java robot class - getting Pixel color after they're painted

Tags: java, swing, graphics, rgb, awtrobot

I need to create a **colorPicker** tool for my little ms paint app.
I originally asked how to switch from my Graphics 2D implementation to a Graphics2D-->BufferedImage one, (and then it would be easy to get the pixels) but I have instead been suggested to get the pixel colors thought the robot class.

First of all, here's my MCEVE: NB. It **cannot be** a single class, it won't save.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Runner {

public static void main(String[] args){

    JFrame Maiframe = new JFrame("Paint");
    Canvas DrawingBoard = new Canvas();
    Maiframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Maiframe.setSize(700, 500);
    Maiframe.add(DrawingBoard);
    Maiframe.setVisible(true);

  }

}



import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;


public class Canvas extends JPanel {

public int xp;  //present x
public int yp;  //present y
public int xo;  //old x
public int yo;  //old y      (Drawing from starting to new point as mouse drags)

public Canvas(){

    super();

    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {   

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {   
            xo = e.getX();
            yo = e.getY();
            Color col = RGBFinder();
            System.out.println("RGB : Red =" + col.getRed() + "Green" +  col.getGreen() + "Blue" + col.getRed());
        }
    });


    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {  //get coords as mouse drags
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

            xp = e.getX();
            yp = e.getY();
            if(SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e))
            repaint();  //call paintcomponent

        }

        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e1){  //keep trak of coords when mouse is not dragging

            xo = e1.getX();
            yo = e1.getY();     
        }
    });

}

public void draw(int x, int y, Graphics g){   //draw the line

    if(xo != 0) 
    g.drawLine(xo, yo, x, y);

    xo = x;    //old x is now present x and so on
    yo = y;     
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    draw(xp, yp, g);    
   }
}

public Color RGBFinder(){

    try{
        robot = new Robot();
    }
    catch(AWTException e){

        System.out.println("Could not create color picker robot");
    }

    PointerInfo pi = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
    Point p = pi.getLocation();
    Color pixelColor = robot.getPixelColor(p.x, p.y);

    //also tried robot.getPixelColor(p.getX(), p.getY());
    //also tried to pass coordinates from listener to RGBFinder, and use those, no luck. (event.getX() ...)

    return pixelColor;

}
```

And it works just fine.

I needed to implement something to get the color from any pixel, when the mouse clicks.

I did this: (adding this method to Canvas, and calling it from the mouse clicker listener)

```
public Color RGBFinder(){

    try{
        robot = new Robot();
    }
    catch(AWTException e){

        System.out.println("Could not create color picker robot");
    }

    PointerInfo pi = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
    Point p = pi.getLocation();
    Color pixelColor = robot.getPixelColor(p.x, p.y);

    //also tried robot.getPixelColor(p.getX(), p.getY());
    //also tried to pass coordinates from listener to RGBFinder, and use those, no luck. (event.getX() ...)

    return pixelColor;

}
```

Example of call:

```
//replace old mouseListener with this

    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {   

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {   
            xo = e.getX();
            yo = e.getY();
            Color col = RGBFinder();
            System.out.println(" da tela Red =" + col.getRed() + "Green" +  col.getGreen() + "Blue" + col.getRed());
        }
    });
```

Unfortunately, from this implementation I get undefined behaviour. The color read is always 255, 255, 255. Exept if I color the hole panel, then it gets it right 9 times out of 10, but in some areas it's still missing it.

I have also tried wrapping the whole thing into a bufferedImage with robot#screenCap but that doesn't even remotely work.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you very much.

EDIT1:

There are doubts as to how a line can remain on screen after a second one has been drawn. I'll provide a screenshot:

[image: Several separated lines. I used a bigger brush size for visibility]

NBB. This works because an instance of Canvas is create inside of a JFrame into Runnable, so the changes are saved, avoiding the need for shapes and arrayLists.

I'll also add a full version of the code which prints wrong RGB results, remember that this does not save the lines as it stands. Please refer to the two separate classes above for testing.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;


public class Canvas extends JPanel{

public int xp;  //present x
public int yp;  //present y
public int xo;  //old x
public int yo;  //old y      (Drawing from starting to new point as mouse drags)
public Robot robot;

public static void main(String[] args){

    JFrame Maiframe = new JFrame("Paint");
    Canvas DrawingBoard = new Canvas();
    Maiframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Maiframe.setSize(700, 500);
    Maiframe.add(DrawingBoard);
    Maiframe.setVisible(true);

  }

public Canvas(){

    super();

            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {   

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {   
            xo = e.getX();
            yo = e.getY();
            Color col = RGBFinder();
            System.out.println("RGB --> Red =" + col.getRed() + "Green" +  col.getGreen() + "Blue" + col.getRed());
        }
    });

    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {  //get coords as mouse drags
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

            xp = e.getX();
            yp = e.getY();
            if(SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e))
            repaint();  //call paintcomponent

        }

        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e1){  //keep trak of coords when mouse is not dragging

            xo = e1.getX();
            yo = e1.getY();     
        }
    });

}

public void draw(int x, int y, Graphics g){   //draw the line

    if(xo != 0) 
    g.drawLine(xo, yo, x, y);

    xo = x;    //old x is now present x and so on
    yo = y;     
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    draw(xp, yp, g);    
   }

 public Color RGBFinder(){

    try{
        robot = new Robot();
    }
    catch(AWTException e){

        System.out.println("Could not create color picker robot");
    }

    PointerInfo pi = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
    Point p = pi.getLocation();
    Color pixelColor = robot.getPixelColor(p.x, p.y);

    //also tried robot.getPixelColor(p.getX(), p.getY());
    //also tried to pass coordinates from listener to RGBFinder, and use those, no luck. (event.getX() ...)

    return pixelColor;

 }
}
```

Comment: I removed the `robot` tag since you're talking about some Java class and not a physical robot :) Besides that, did you check the correct coordinates are being sent to `robot`? Did you check which coordinate system is used by `PointerInfo`? If you're using the wrong coordinate system your position might be outside the canvas/panel and thus return the wrong values.

Comment: Yes, I have. The coordinates are correct. Thank you very very much for reading and helping anyhow.

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Don't call you class "Canvas". That is an AWT class name and is confusing. Use a better descriptive class name.

Comment: `First of all, here's my MCVE:` - that is NOT an MCVE. The code should be in a single class file that we can copy/paste/compile/execute.

Comment: My class name wasn't Canvas, I translated the code from Italian to make it undestandable and that was the closest thing I found.  I'm sorry but this is as close as I can get to the MCVE, I don't have the knowledge yet to put everything in the same class, please create separate files if you have the time. Thank you very much for your help anyhow.

Comment: `I don't have the knowledge yet to put everything in the same class,` - What? All you do is copy the main() method into the "Canvas" class. You add your MouseListener code and the RGBFinder code to the same class. `if you have the time.` - this is your question. We don't have the time to write or tidy up the code for you. If you want help you make the effort. Now is a good time to learn how to create the MCVE/SSCCE to simplify the code so we can see exactly what you are doing. We don't want a verbal description of what you think you are doing.

Comment: For example check out the `ComponentEventDemo` code found in the Swing tutorial on [How to Write an ItemListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/itemlistener.html). The basic difference is 1) you are doing cusom painting on the panel, instead of addind components to the panel. 2) you are using a MouseListener, not an ItemListner.

Comment: I'm sorry sir I know it seems obvious to you but it's still very new to me. I have tried to the best of my abilities to do as you asked, now it's all in one class, please let me know if there's anything else I can do. I hope that in that full class it will become clear why robot is giving wrong rgb colors, I just can't figure it out. Everything else works, I have made color pallettes, brushes, shapes, all sorts of things, but robot will not read any correct RGB value whatsoever. I'm sorry it must be obvious but I just don't see it.

Comment: You can't just copy two files into one. The main() method should just be another method in the "Canvas" class. The code MUST compile. How do you expect us to test your code if it doe not compile? Look at the link I gave you above and create a proper MCVE based on the structure of the code in that link. `but it's still very new to me` - maybe but you are not reading the comments. I specifically stated the code should `copy/paste/compile/execute`. Does the code you posted compile??? I don't have time to sit here waiting for you to post a proper MCVE.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not able to merge the classes. If I create an instance of Canvas inside of Canvas itelf(instead of runner), it's not gonna work. I'm only able to make it work in two separate classes. (I fixed the imports that caused it not to compile, however, this new design prevents it from saving the drawings.) I would really appreciate it if you could please paste Canvas and Runner in two separate file classes, if you don't have the time I'll understand, thank you anyway.

Comment: To me you still have to define your question (where are you clicking and you dont get the color? are you clicking on the borders of your screen??) For sure the robot will get the color.

Answer (score 3):

> my little ms paint app

Well its not much of a paint app. All it does is draw a single line. Whenever you attempt to draw the second line the first will be removed.

So the first step you need to do is decide how you want the painting to work. There are two common approaches:

1. Store Objects you want to paint in an `ArrayList` and then the `paintComponent(...)` method will paint each Object in the List.
2. Paint directly to a `BufferedImage` and then the `paintComponent(...)` method can just paint the `BufferedImage`.

Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for working examples of both of these approaches and give the pros/cons of using each approach.

> I have instead been suggested to get the pixel colors thought the robot class

It depends which painting approach you want to use.

If you use the `Draw on Component` approach then you would use the `MouseInfo` and `Robot` to get the pixel color:

```
PointerInfo pi = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
Point p = pi.getLocation();
System.out.println( robot.getPixelColor(p.x, p.y) );
```

If you use the `Draw on Image` approach then you would get the pixel color from the `BufferedImage`:

```
int rgb = bufferedImage.getRGB(mouseEvent.getX(), mouseEvent.getY());
Color color = new Color( rgb );
System.out.println( color );
```

**Final Update**

You still have not posted a SSCCE. The code you posted does NOT draw a line. Even if it did draw a line, how do you expect us to click (with accuracy) a single pixel line.

The point of a SSCCE is to demonstrate the concept you are asking about. You are asking how to get the Color of a pixel on your panel. How the drawing gets on the panel is irrelevant to the question so the painting code should be as simple as possible.

Following is a proper SSCCE. Note:

1. The `createAndShowGUI()` and `main()` methods will be the same for all SSCCE. The difference is the `DrawingPanel code/class will change to demonstrate your problem.
2. The custom painting is hardcoded. There is no need for mouseMoved/mouseDragged logic (unless that is the problem) you are trying to solve. All you care about is having different colors to click on.
3. Just use a simple System.out.println(...) to display the value of the Color object.

All I did was copy the relevant pieces of code from you class and remove the irrelevant code to keep the code simple and straight forward. Anybody can do that.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DrawingCanvas extends JPanel
{
    private Robot robot;

    public DrawingCanvas()
    {
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
            {
                try
                {
                    robot = new Robot();
                }
                catch(Exception re) { System.out.println(re); }

                PointerInfo pi = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
                Point p = pi.getLocation();
                Color pixelColor = robot.getPixelColor(p.x, p.y);
                System.out.println(pixelColor);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.setColor( Color.RED );
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 40, 40);

        g.setColor( Color.GREEN );
        g.fillRect(40, 40, 40, 40);

        g.setColor( Color.BLUE );
        g.fillRect(80, 80, 40, 40);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JPanel panel = new DrawingCanvas();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("DrawingCanvas");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() ); // Java 8 only
/*
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
*/
    }
}
```

Just copy/paste/compile/execute to see that the code works.

I'll let you figure out why your code doesn't appear to work.

> NBB. This works because an instance of Canvas is create inside of a JFrame into Runnable, so the changes are saved, avoiding the need for shapes and arrayLists.

That statement is completely wrong. Painting done with the Graphics Object in the paintComponent() method is only temporary until the next time the paintComponent() method is invoked.

For example add the following code after the frame.setVisible() statement:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();
        g.setColor( Color.YELLOW );
        g.fillRect(120, 120, 40, 40);
    }
});
```

The yellow square will disappear when the frame is resized. For permanent painting you need to use one of the two approaches I suggested in my original answer.

Edit 2:

This is the output I get when I click on the red, green, blue, background respectively:

```
C:\Java>java DrawingCanvas
java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0]
java.awt.Color[r=0,g=255,b=0]
java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=255]
java.awt.Color[r=238,g=238,b=238]
```

Comment: Hi, I have of course taken some of the code away to make this easy to read. It works, when I draw a line, it's stored in the g object, so it doesn't get erased when I draw the second one.
I have tried the first approach, but it somehow does not work. I get wrong colors. (And that's the problem in the question).
I wanted to go with the second approach, but I can't figure out how to draw on the buffered image.

Comment: `, it's stored in the g object, so it doesn't get erased when I draw the second one` - no it isn't. Nothing is stored in the Graphics Object. You either store the information in the ArrayList or a BufferedImage. `I have tried the first approach, but it somehow does not work.` - post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.  `but I can't figure out how to draw on the buffered image` - which is why I provided you with the link.

Comment: But the lines are not disappearing when I draw. I am not using arrayList nor bufferedImages. The full code is in my question, including the code for the SSCCE. The robot reads the wrong colors.

Comment: You didn't get much help in your last question. I'm trying to be helpful here but since you haven't posted a proper MCVE/SSCCE I can't provide any more help.

Comment: Please tell me what you need in order to help. I lack the knowledge to make all of this work in the same class.

Comment: @LucaRossini, see edit for a SSCCE that demonstrates your basic logic is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, the logic you're using with robot resembles my own, however, I can't get it to work. I have not used the bufferedImage, nor the arrayList, yet somehow, the paintComponent doesn't erase everything. I suspect that the "somehow" hides the reason behind the failure of robot. I'll try to re-code the drawing process to follow an ArrayList of shapes and see the results.

Comment: Edit- I have tried your code (copied, pasted, compiled, executed), and it doesn't work in the slightest. I get 255, 255, 255 or 253, 253, 253 on all three squares, as well as on the background. I'm gonna bang my head on a wall if this turns out to be a problem with my hardware or IDE. Where are you running it?

Comment: @LucaRossini, `I'm gonna bang my head on a wall if this turns out to be a problem with my hardware or IDE` - and this is another reason why a proper SSCCE should be posted with every question. I'm using JDK8 on Windows 7. `I have not used the bufferedImage, nor the arrayList, yet somehow, the paintComponent doesn't erase everything.` - every time you the paintComponent() method is invoked the super.paintComponent(...) will clear the background so you lose the painting. See second edit for my output.

Comment: Any ideas why I copypaste it and get different results? I'm using JDK 8 on windows 10. Both eclipse and terminal give me the same results.

Comment: @LucaRossini, In your other question you where given a link to a "duplicate question". Did you download the SSCCE provided in that answer and test it? Did that code work properly? Did you verify that the Point return from the MouseInfo class is reasonable? One way might be to use the `SwingUtilities.convertPointToScreen(...) method to convert the mouse point from the MouseEvent. Both points should be the same.

Comment: Otherwise you could probably use my code as a proper SSCCE and ask a better question stating that the code runs on Java 8 using Windows 7 but not Windows 10 and see if anybody else has a suggestion. Maybe you will get lucky and another person running Window 10 will text the code and provide their results. Again, this is why a proper SSCCE should be posted with the initial question. In the future don't expect people answering the question to provide the SSCCE.

Comment: The coordinates are correct. The code provided in the answer you are referring to doesn't work either. I suspect it might have something to do with high dpi monitors (such as my own). I'll post another question on this matter shortly. I'm sorry for the lack of an SSCCE on my part, on the other hand, since I was not able to create it (I have tried for hours, I'm just to new to java), I guess asking without was the only way. Thank you so much for your help anyway.

Comment: `I suspect it might have something to do with high dpi monitors (such as my own). I'll post another question on this matter shortly` - Maybe. Post your resolution is the question as well. The more info you provide You could always try changing the resolution of your monitor to a lower resolution to see if it makes a difference. In any case you have already been given a solution to your problem. You can use a `BufferedImage` and then the pixel color is not dependent on using the Robot or the hardware of your platform.